# Xcode error trying to build project exported from Unity 5.6.5

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, build-error

I'm using XCode 9.2 and Unity 5.6.5f1

I am trying to make an iOS build of my project. I can successfully export to an XCode project, but when I try to create an archive in XCode, I get a bunch of errors that I can't make head nor tail of. I'm guessing some library isn't being imported/connected? I'm a bit lost at sea here...

[image]

I've turned off bitcode, set the minimum os to 8, but neither seem to have helped. I'm not really sure how to start dealing with this error... I wonder if I'm missing something obvious? Many thanks.

Comment: Update your question with any third party SDKs you're using. Your screenshot is showing link errors for a Facebook SDK.

Comment: We're using Firebase, Facebook, Google Play Services. Is there a list in XCode I can screengrab? How do I resolve a link error?

Comment: The left side of your screenshot is showing the issue navigator. It's cut off in your screenshot but there's a series of small buttons at the top of the navigator. Click the left one to show the project navigator, which shows the files and frameworks in your project. If you don't see any listings for Firebase, Facebook, or Google Play Services, you may need to add them to the project. Missing libraries and frameworks can cause link errors.I have not worked with these frameworks so I can't give you any more guidance on this.

Comment: I see all the libraries I'm using listed there, and when I dive down, they all appear to be correctly installed. How would I manually add them if I wanted to?

Comment: Select your project from the project navigator to show the project editor. Select your app target from the editor. Click the Build Phases button at the top of the editor. Click the disclosure triangle next to the Link Binary with Build Phases build phase. From there you can add libraries.